# Javascript constructor: Accessing outside variable

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor, scope

I try to access an object which is global; it's a kind of a preset.

```
var perks = {health: 100, attack: 10};

var player = function(hp) {
   this.stats = perks;

   //Changing some standard values..
   this.stats["health"] = hp; 
}

var Peter = new player(200);
var Steven = new player(300);
```

I hope you get my intention; the problem is, that it won't work correct, and I'm not even sure what it does wrong. If I create more than one player, e.g. Steven, Collin and James, every player has the same perks. In this example Peter and Steven both have 300 health.

If I change the line

```
this.stats = perks;
```

to

```
this.stats = {health: 100, attack: 10};
```

everything works like intended. Peter and Steven both have their own stats.
How do I access the global `var perks`?

Comment: because both of them refers to the same instance of `perks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because in JavaScript object does not copy that way, thats why all of your players using the same `perks` object.
There is a few ways to solve it:

1. Create new object with a function (object own constructor).

   ```
   function createPerks() {
       return {
           health: 100,
           attack: 10
       };
   }

   var player = function(hp) {
       this.stats = createPerks();

       //Changing some standard values..
       this.stats["health"] = hp; 
   }

   var Peter = new player(200);
   var Steven = new player(300);
   ```
2. Create new object each time and use constants for default values:

   ```
   var BASE_HEALTH = 100;
   var BASE_ATTACK = 10;

   var player = function(hp) {
       this.stats = {
           health: BASE_HEALTH,
           attack: BASE_ATTACK
       };

       //Changing some standard values..
       this.stats["health"] = hp; 
   }

   var Peter = new player(200);
   var Steven = new player(300);
   ```
3. Use `Object.create` (works in IE9+, but shimable for older browsers):

   ```
   var perks = {health: 100, attack: 10};

   var player = function(hp) {
       this.stats = Object.create(perks);

       //Changing some standard values..
       this.stats["health"] = hp; 
   }

   var Peter = new player(200);
   var Steven = new player(300);
   ```

   Keep in mind that `Object.create` does not clone an object but inherit one object from another.

   `Object.create` shim for old browsers by [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/):

   ```
   if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
       Object.create = function (o) {
           function F() {}
           F.prototype = o;
           return new F();
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The moment you write `this.stats = perks;` both of them refer to the same `object` that is `{health: 100, attack: 10}`. So any changes made to any one of them will always affect the other.

As `var Steven = new player(300);` is the last value you assigned. All your players will now have `{health: 300, attack: 10}`